# UINavigationController not working in UIPopOverController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

In my Ipad App(ios6) I'm working on `UIPopOverController`. In the `UIPopOverController` i'm showing camera. My requirement is when i'm pressing camera capture button it push to another view controller. In that view controller I want to show the image taken from camera.

I'm using this code:

```
ImageCropViewController *cropViewController = [[ImageCropViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageCropViewController" bundle:nil];
cropViewController.sourceImage = image;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cropViewController];


[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have tried a lot and googled,but I did not find any solution. It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.

Comment: DO you want to push or present ? Also where are you using UIPopoverController ?

Comment: I want to push.@Flappy

Answer (score 0):

I think your `self.navigationController` is `nil`. You create nav controller, but use it like wrapper for your cropper controller. As Example:

```
  //in AppDelegate
  SomeController *controller = [SomeController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
 self.window.rootViewController = controller;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

 // later
 // asume that self is SomeController
 ImageCropViewController *cropViewController = [[ImageCropViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageCropViewController" bundle:nil];
  cropViewController.sourceImage = image;

  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cropViewController];


  [self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];  // now it will be work
```

UPD: I don't see at first time that you using `UIPopOverController`, so it may not work. But `UIPopOverController` doesn't have navigationController property.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution:

```
ImageCropViewController *cropViewController = [[ImageCropViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageCropViewController" bundle:nil];
cropViewController.sourceImage = image;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cropViewController animated:YES];
```

I Have written the below code in  `ImageCropViewController`'s `ViewWillAppear`

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(450, 350);
```